# Шифр зашифровки изображений

Tags: изображения, шифрование

Есть вот такая строка:
"eyJ0ZXh0dXJlcyI6eyJTS0lOIjp7InVybCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vZWR1Y2F0aW9uLm1pbmVjcmFmdC5uZXQvd3AtY29udGVudC91cGxvYWRzL3ByaW5lc2ltbmVmb3RvY2hlbG92ZWthcGF5a2FCeU15cF9NeXAucG5nIn19fQ"

С нее как то получается изображение. Каким шифром зашифровано изображение(с альфа каналом)?

Вот скриншот, но зашифрована текстура:

[image: Вот скриншот, но зашифрована текстура]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

base64

```
{"textures":{"SKIN":{"url":"https://education.minecraft.net/wp-content/uploads/prinesimnefotochelovekapaykaByMyp_Myp.png"}}}
```